# Edit Record Page on iPad Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, page-layout, mobile, lightning-app-builder

We've downloaded the official Salesforce app from the App Store to a 2nd Gen iPad Pro. What we're currently stuck with, is that we cant seem to update the record view on the iPad app.

We thought that the app would behave somewhat like the app for iPhones, where we can specify a record page in the Lightning App Builder, but no matter what we try, we cannot add or remove anything from the record page on the iPad.

We can change the Page Layout buttons and so fourth, but we need to be able to add and remove LWCs.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I think that the most probable reason is caching. A lot of stuff is cached in the app for performance reasons.
For any change in layout to be visible you need to clear the cache!